# Building .SLN files on Windows without Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, build, sln-file

I have recently been trying to set up my CMake environment and some 'hello world' code in C++. I added a `CMakeLists.txt` and added my configurations, but when I ran `cmake .` in the command line, something was different from all of the tutorials.

The people on the tutorials were using a Unix based system, so the command `cmake .` was producing a 'makefile'. They then built the makefile using the command `make`.

Since I'm on windows, it generated a msvc `.sln` file instead of a makefile. My question is - how can I build the .sln file, similar to how they did it on Linux? I want to do it without Visual Studio 2019 and preferably in the command prompt.

I have tried searching for this question, but haven't found what I'm looking for. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `Visual Studio > New Project > Cmake project`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should *never* do an in-tree build with `cmake .`. It invites problems in the form of name clashes and makes it nearly impossible to get a clean rebuild.

If you're using a recent version of CMake (which you should be), the standard way to build a project varies on whether the backend generator is *single-config* or *multi-config*.

If it's **single-config** (like Make or Ninja), then the commands are:

```
$ cmake -G Ninja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -S /path/to/sources -B /path/to/build
$ cmake --build /path/to/build
```

The directory `/path/to/build` doesn't need to exist when you invoke CMake. If you wanted a `Debug` build, rather than `Release`, you would just replace that in the first line. You should *never* run a single-config generator without setting `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`.

If it's **multi-config**, like Visual Studio, then the commands are:

```
$ cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A x64 -Thost=x64 -S /path/to/sources -B /path/to/build
$ cmake --build /path/to/build --config Release
```

The major difference here is that the config is specified in the *second* (build) command, rather than the *first* (configure).